# Get tab and enter event in form in panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012 I have a panel in FormA which loads FormB.

```
FormB = New FormB
FormB.TopLevel = False
FormB.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
FormB.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
FormB.Visible = True
Panel1.Controls.Add(FormB)
```

FormB contains some TextBoxes and a Button.  When I try to tab through the TextBoxes in FormB the focus jumps to controls in FormA.  I'm not able to get the keyboard enter event in FormB neither. I started with a bunch of independent forms but I am now trying use Tabs and Panels to navigate through the app.  It would be great if I could use my existing form in panels to achieve this.

Comment: I assume this is a Windows Forms program, so I added that tag. It's best to not force us to make assumptions, though...

Comment: @john Yes it is a windows form application and thanks.

Answer (score -1):

do you know "KeyPreview"? If you activate this, it may help you to catch the events directly on your active form. By default this is disabled and you can find it in your form-properties.